# Split dataframe based on a continuous column value, not present in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a dataframe into several ones based on a list with the splitting points or threshold, which don't necessarily need to be in the reference column. I haven't quite found an answer for this

| Values | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Any |
| 3 | Any |
| 5 | Any |
| 8 | Any |
| 11 | Any |
| 16 | Any |

The list would be something like: thresholds = [4,10]. Therefore the return would need to be 3 dataframes containing two rows each.
I haven't quite found this one and was starting to look into a for loop to check row by row if it is higher or lower, but having the thresholds list I imagined that there might be a more straightforward way? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another looping option

```
thresholds = [4,10]
thresholds = [float('-inf')] +  thresholds + [float('inf')] 

empty = []
for i in range(len(thresholds)-1):
    t_start = thresholds[i]
    t_end = thresholds[i+1]
    temp = df.query('Values >  @t_start & Values <= @t_end')
    empty.append(temp)    
empty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different bins using `pandas.cut`, then split the dataframe based on these vales:

```py
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Values'], [float('-inf'),4,10, float('inf')])
out=[df[df['bins'].eq(bin)] for bin in df['bins'].unique()]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
for o in out:
    print(o)
    
   Values Another header         bins
0       2            Any  (-inf, 4.0]
1       3            Any  (-inf, 4.0]
   Values Another header         bins
2       5            Any  (4.0, 10.0]
3       8            Any  (4.0, 10.0]
   Values Another header         bins
4      11            Any  (10.0, inf]
5      16            Any  (10.0, inf]
```

You can `drop` the `bins` column later if needed.